# pass component according to v-if - Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am trying to create a parent component with all kinds of graphics, and depending on what I need to pass on a specific graphic (raise a child) to another component, but I don't necessarily know how I would dynamically do it for the user.

my html charts (chart.vue)

```html
    <template>  
        <div >
          <bars v-if="type == 'bar'">
             <div class="row gutter-sm">
                <div class="col-md-3"> 
                   <apexchart  ref="chart1" type="bar" :options="options" :series="updatedData"></apexchart>
                </div>
             </div> 
                <div class="col-md-3"> 
                   <apexchart ref="chart3" type="bar" :options="options3" :series="updatedData"></apexchart>
                </div>
           </bars>
           <lines v-if="type == 'line'">
              <div class="row gutter-sm">
                <div class="col-md-3"> 
                   <apexchart ref="chart4" type="line" :options="options4" :series="updatedData"></apexchart>
                </div>  
             </div>
           </lines>
       </div>
    <template>
```

If I wanted to pass on bar graphics to my menu.vue, would it be like this?

my html menu

```html
    <template>  
        <div >
          <table class="data-table-2" style="min-width: 800px">
             <charts type="bar"/>
          </table>
       </div>
    <template>
```

scripts menu

```js
   <script>
   
       import charts from "./charts.vue"
       
       export default {
         name: 'menu',
         components: {
            charts
         }
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: When the parent component passes the value to the child component, the child component needs to receive it in props, and the type and default value of the value can also be set

Answer (score 1):

The way you pass values from the parent component to the child component is wrong

```
<template>  
    <div >
      <table class="data-table-2" style="min-width: 800px">
         <charts :type='bar'/>
         <charts :type='line'/>
         <charts />
      </table>
   </div>
<template>
```

child component receiving value, and you can set a default value:

```
// init in child component
props: {
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: 'bar' // set a default value
  }
},
data(){
 ...
}
```

then you can use type in child component

```
<template>  
    <div >
      <bars v-if"type == 'bar'">
         <div class="row gutter-sm">
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
               <apexchart  ref="chart1" type="bar" :options="options" :series="updatedData"></apexchart>
            </div>
         </div> 
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
               <apexchart ref="chart3" type="bar" :options="options3" :series="updatedData"></apexchart>
            </div>
       </bars>
       <lines v-if"type == 'line'">
          <div class="row gutter-sm">
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
               <apexchart ref="chart4" type="line" :options="options4" :series="updatedData"></apexchart>
            </div>  
         </div>
       </lines>
   </div>
<template>
```

Comment: in case I want to pass 2 children components, I insert two props?

Comment: @Christian Guimarães  props init in child Component,

Comment: unfortunately something is still missing, my component did not redenalize on screen

Comment: @Christian Guimarães  You can console the type in the life cycle of the child component to see if the value is received

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a Props in child component.

```
//Child Component Script
export default ChildComponent {
    data() {
        return {}
    },
    props: {
        type: string,
    }
}
```

In parent component you need to call child component and pass type data like this
//parent component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <child-component :type="line"/>
    </div>
</template>
```